# Printing Out Object In Java

Tags: java, object, constructor, instantiation

I have a `file` that has the following content:

```
5
Derrick Rose
1 15 19 26 33 46
Kobe Bryant
17 19 33 34 46 47
Pau Gasol
1 4 9 16 25 36
Kevin Durant
17 19 34 46 47 48
LeBron James
5 10 17 19 34 47
```

I'm trying to put the names and then numbers for the ticket in an array in my ticket constructor, however when I instantiate my ticket object and try to display it I get the following:

```
Tickets: lottery$Ticket@33909752
Tickets: lottery$Ticket@55f96302
Tickets: lottery$Ticket@3d4eac69
Tickets: lottery$Ticket@42a57993
Tickets: lottery$Ticket@75b84c92
```

Does the problem in my constructor for ticket or is it impossible to print an array without making it a string first?

```
int lim = scan.nextInt();
scan.nextLine();
for(int i = 0; i < lim; i++)
{
        String name = scan.nextLine();
        String num = scan.nextLine();
        String[] t = num.split(" ");
        int[] tichold = new int[t.length];

        for(int j = 0; j < t.length; j++)
        {
            tichold[j] = Integer.parseInt(t[j]);
        }


        Ticket ticket = new Ticket(name, tichold);
        System.out.println("Ticket: " + ticket);
    }
    scan.close();
}

public static class Ticket
{
    public String name;
    public int[] tarray;

    public Ticket(String name, int[] tarray)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.tarray = tarray;
    }
}
```

Comment: Override `toString` in `Ticket`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to provide `toString` method for it. Here is sample, which you can use:

```java
@Override
public String toString() {
  return "Ticket{" +
      "name='" + name + '\'' +
      ", tarray=" + Arrays.toString(tarray) +
      '}';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to accomplish that you need to write an overiding toString method and write in there want you want.

```
    public String toString(){
    return //whatever you need goes here and will be printed when you try and
    //print the object            
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You must override the toString method which is inherited from the Object class:

```
@Override
public String toString(){
return //Enter the format you require
}
```

Remember ticket is a reference variable so when you print it out, you will get the hashcode along with the name of the class of which the object is an instance.