# Iterating through ArrayList of Objects in Java

Tags: java

I have tried to find an answer to my question here but with no luck - please let me know if this was already answered and I will delete this question.

I want to iterate through an ArrayList of playing cards, here is my code:

```
public static void showCards(ArrayList<Card> cards){
    Iterator iterator = cards.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        String object = String.valueOf(iterator.next());
        System.out.println(object);
    }
}
```

I want to print the value of each card, but I am only getting the reference:

```
com.company.Card@4517d9a3
com.company.Card@4517d9a3
```

I have tried looping through as well - same thing. What am I doing wrong?

Card class if needed:

```
public class Card {
private CardSuit cardSuit;
private CardValue cardValue;

public Card(CardSuit cardSuit,  CardValue cardValue) {
    this.cardValue = cardValue;
    this.cardSuit = cardSuit;
}

public CardValue getCardValue() {
    return cardValue;
}

public CardSuit getCardSuit() {
    return cardSuit;
}

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Printing Out Object In Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32365830/printing-out-object-in-java)

Comment: `Object#toString` returns the fully-qualified class name and a hex-value of the hashcode (usually the memory address if not overridden). You need to override the `#toString` method if you want a custom output.

Comment: Check out this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29140403/10946202). It has clear explanation why you are seeing that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is more complicated than it needs to be:

1. You can use a so called enhanced for loop instead of an `Iterator`. It's the same, but shorter.
2. You don't have to call `String.valueOf()` or `toString()`. You can call `System.out.println()` for any object in java and it will automatically convert it to a `String`.
3. If a while-loop only does one thing, you don't need the brackets.

The code now looks like this:

```
public static void showCards(ArrayList<Card> cards) {
    for (Card card : cards) System.out.println(card);
}
```

Because this is so simple, you might not even need `showCards` anymore, but could directly use a for-loop.

---

To convert an object to a String, java uses this weird notation:

> full class name + "@" + hash code in hex

If you want java to convert a `Card` to a `String` a different way, you need to override the `toString()` method in your `Card` class:

```
public String toString() {
    return "Card with suit " + cardSuit + " and value + " cardValue;
}
```

(You will probably have to do the same for your classes `CardSuit` and `CardValue`).

Answer (score 0):

You can overrite default method toString:

```
public class Card {
...
@Overrite
public String toString() {
 return "{ cardSuit=" + cardSuit + ", cardValue=" + cardValue "}";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

also you can cast object to Card and use getCardValue():

```
public static void showCards(ArrayList<Card> cards){
    Iterator iterator = cards.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        Object object = iterator.next();
        Card c = (Card) object;
        System.out.println(c.getCardValue());
    }
}
```